# Why won't my browser set the px font-text size to what I've set in CSS

Tags: html, css, inspect

I've set the pixel size in my CSS to 50px but in the browser when expand my navigation menu the it sets the px size to 55.15.. etc. This same problem affects the Log Action, View Action and Keysystem pages. It doesn't affect the facilities info page. There is a gap below the first link on the drop down menu as well. I image the pixel size of the text is causing this because, again, it doesn't happen on my main index page.

I've tried changing the px to an rem value that will scale it to 50px from the page default of 38px. It also doesn't solve the problem.

CSS is as follows. .nav_main a is where I have set the px size to 50px.

```
* {
  font-family: Arial;
  margin: 0px;
}

html,body
{
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-size: 38px;
    overflow: visible;
}

h1 {
  display: block;
}

.nav_main {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #282828;
  overflow: auto;
}

.nav_main a {
  width: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-top: 32px;
  padding-bottom: 32px;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #fff;
}

.nav_main .icon {
  display: inline;
  float: right;
  width: auto;
  padding: 27.5px;
}

.nav_main .icon_clicked {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: auto;
  padding: 27.5px
}
```

This is the log action page html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Facilities Portal - Log Action</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
</head>
<body>

    <header>
        <h1>Facilities Portal</h1>

        <div id="navMain" class="nav_main">
                <a id="facInfoL" href="index.html" style="display: none">Facilities Info</a>
                <a id="logActionL" class="activeNav" href="logaction.html" style="display: none">Log Action</a>
                <a id="viewActionL" href="viewaction.html" style="display: none">View Actions</a>
                <a id="keySystemL" href="keysystem.html" style="display: none">Key System</a>
                <a id="burgerIcon" class="icon" onclick="expandMenu()">&#9776;</a>
        </div>

    </header>

    <main>
        <form action="#" id="logActionForm">
            <p>Your Name: </p><input type="text" name="FullName" placeholder="Type your name here...">
            <p>Email: </p><input type="email" name="EmailAddress" placeholder="Type your email here...">
            <p>Issue: </p>
                <select>
                    <option value"" disabled selected hidden>Please choose...</option>
                    <option value="hnf">Health and Safety</option>
                    <option value="comfort">Comfort</option>
                    <option value="other">Other</option>
                </select>

            <p>Description: </p><input type="text" name="Desc" placeholder="Brief description of issue...">
            <p>Details: </p><input type="text" name="Details" placeholder="Extra details here...">
            <p>Upload Picture</p><input type="file" name="pic" accept="image/*">
            <button type="submit" form="logActionForm" value="submit">Submit</button>
            <button type="reset" value="reset">Clear</button>
            <button type="button" value="viewPrevActions">View Previous Actions</button>
        </form>
    </main>

    <footer>
        <p>Author: Scott Law</p>
        <p>Copyright &copy; 2019</p>
    </footer>

    <script src="js/common.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

This is the index page html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <title>Facilites Portal Main</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
</head>
<body>

    <header>
        <h1>Facilities Portal</h1>
            <div id="navMain" class="nav_main">
                    <a id="facInfoL" class="activeNav" href="index.html" style="display: none">Facilities Info</a>
                    <a id="logActionL" href="logaction.html" style="display: none">Log Action</a>
                    <a id="viewActionL" href="viewaction.html" style="display: none">View Actions</a>
                    <a id="keySystemL" href="keysystem.html" style="display: none">Key System</a>
                    <a id="burgerIcon" class="icon" onclick="expandMenu()">&#9776;</a>
            </div>

    </header>

    <main>
        <a href="logaction.html"><img class="portal-img" src="images/spanners-tools.jpg" alt="Log Action Img"></a>
        <a href="viewaction.html"><img class="portal-img" src="images/clipboard.jpg" alt="View Actions Img"></a>
        <a href="#"><img class="portal-img" src="images/batch-books.jpg" alt="Facilities Infomation Img"></a>
        <a href="keysystem.html"><img class="portal-img" src="images/close-up-keys.jpg" alt="Key System Img"></a>
    </main>

    <footer>
        <p>Author: Scott Law</p>
        <p>Copyright &copy; 2019</p>
    </footer>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/common.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Browser picture for log action page (the error is on this page). Highlighted yellow is the problem. This occurs on the log action, view action and key system pages.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LWfUl.jpg

Browser picture for index page (it works correctly)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ev4ak.jpg

I would like for the browser to follow the CSS i've set like on the index page. The other pages don't follow suit for some reason.

Comment: Do you have a live example somewhere? Can't tell the problem from these pictures and the code.

Comment: This the index page https://codepen.io/lawscott1988/pen/yrvbXG

Comment: This is the log action page https://codepen.io/lawscott1988/pen/EJQmoa

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't emulate what i'm describing. I'm not sure how to put codepen into a mobile phone view if that makes sense? It only seems to be doing it in that view.

Comment: Ah, it's for mobile? In that case check if the page isn't to wide for the viewport. Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26570301/why-some-font-sizes-rendered-larger-in-mobile-browsers)

Comment: From your link I've added <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> to the head data of each page. The issue seems to be fixed. However everything is very large now. Would it just be a matter of resizing everything in the css to fit the mobile screen?